# Minimal distance in dotfill

Tags: spacing, indexing

I'm generating an index with `dotfill`s, such that my ind looks like this (extract):

```
\item\raggedright l\IeC {\`e}pre\dotfill \transform{21}
\item\raggedright libre arbitre\dotfill \transform{1}
\item\raggedright louange\dotfill \transform{245}, \transform{253}
```

In this case, `\transform{245}` and `\transform{253}` just fit on the line with `louange`, resulting in this:

[image: index touching]

Here is a MWE reproducing such a behavior:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\parbox{3.4cm}{
\LaTeX\dotfill powerful, useful
}

\end{document}
```

which gives me:

[image: dotfill... without dots]

How could I ensure a minimal distance between `louange` and the first entry, having `9 septembre` move to the next line in this case?

Comment: do you want `9 septembre` to be continued on the left, or set flush right?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
 {\def\hfill{\hskip 10pt plus 1fill}\dotfill}
```

will be at least 10pt.

Comment: This solution does not work for me. When adding this into the preamble an error yields: `Missing \begin{document}.  {\def\hfill{\hskip 10pt plus 1fill}\dotfill}`

Comment: @bmv impossible to say anything just given that information. If you have an error make a complete small test document and post as a question not as a comment on an  year old post.