# Adjusting dotfill for custom table of notations

Tags: tables, table-of-contents, formatting, fill

Consider the following code/picture:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{2.62cm}@{}p{9.5cm}@{}}
$\varliminf,\varlimsup$ & test test test test test test test test test test test  \dotfill 123\\
$\varliminf,\varlimsup$ & test test test test test test test test test test test test  \dotfill 123\\
$\varliminf,\varlimsup$ & test test test test test test test test test test test test test  \dotfill 123\\
$\varliminf,\varlimsup$ & test test test test test test test test test test test test test test  \dotfill 123\\
$\varliminf,\varlimsup$ & test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test  \dotfill 123\\
$\liminf,\limsup$ & idem  \dotfill 123 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

> I'm not satisfied with the item 3 and 4 of 6: too few space(filled with dots!) before the number in 3, and in 4 the dots are missing. I tried to adapt [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86944), but without success. I just do not understand how it works. `\zdotfill` should not introduce unfilled space (unfilled=without dots), it should just have a minimal length of 1cm (filled with dots) and everything else should be as by `\dotfill`.

Wrong code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\zdotfill}{\hskip 1cm plus 1fill\dotfill}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{2.62cm}@{}p{9.5cm}@{}}
$\varliminf,\varlimsup$ & test test test test test test test test test test test  \zdotfill 123\\
$\varliminf,\varlimsup$ & test test test test test test test test test test test test  \zdotfill 123\\
$\varliminf,\varlimsup$ & test test test test test test test test test test test test test  \zdotfill 123\\
$\varliminf,\varlimsup$ & test test test test test test test test test test test test test test  \zdotfill 123\\
$\varliminf,\varlimsup$ & test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test  \zdotfill 123\\
$\liminf,\limsup$ & idem  \zdotfill 123 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to:

- restrict the redefinition of `\hfill` to a group that finishes immediately after `\dotfill`, otherwise you are going to spoil other `\hfill` commands used in the document (possibly internally by LaTeX);
- make sure the leaders inserted by `\dotfill` from your `\zdotfill` do not constitute a valid breakpoint, otherwise they just get discarded when they happen to be at the end of a line, according to TeX's paragraph breaking algorithm (what you witnessed);
- make sure there is no space token before your calls to `\zdotfill`, otherwise this is yet another possible breakpoint at the precise place where you don't want one.

I'll rename your `\zdotfill` to `\mindotfill` in order not to confuse it with a command from [zref](https://ctan.org/pkg/zref) (precisely, from its `dotfill` module).

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\mindotfill}{%
  \nolinebreak
  {\def\hfill{\hskip 1cm plus 1fill\relax}%
   \dotfill
  }%
}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{2.62cm}@{}p{9.5cm}@{}}
$\varliminf,\varlimsup$ & test test test test test test test test test test test\mindotfill 123\\
$\varliminf,\varlimsup$ & test test test test test test test test test test test test\mindotfill 123\\
$\varliminf,\varlimsup$ & test test test test test test test test test test test test test\mindotfill 123\\
$\varliminf,\varlimsup$ & test test test test test test test test test test test test test test\mindotfill 123\\
$\varliminf,\varlimsup$ & test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test\mindotfill 123\\
$\liminf,\limsup$ & idem\mindotfill 123\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot]

For your information, `\dotfill` is defined as:

```
\dotfill:
macro:->\leavevmode \cleaders \hb@xt@ .44em{\hss .\hss }\hfill \kern \z@
```

What `\mindotfill` does here is to modify the 〈skip〉 used by `\cleaders`, which is produced by `\hfill` in this definition (`\hb@xt@ .44em{\hss .\hss }` just produces an `\hbox` of suitable width containing a single dot). Leaders are assimilated to glue by TeX, that's why they get discarded at the end of a line.

Comment: wow! it is perfect! thank you

Comment: Glad to here that. I added a little explanation of how this works at the end (but if you've never read about leaders, that won't be quite enough to understand everything—they are explained in the TeXbook).

Comment: very interesting explanations, especially the local redefinition of a command. very usefull

Comment: If you look closely, David Carlisle's post that you linked did the local redefinition correctly. :)

Comment: that is the point: I could not understand what he was doing, without an explanation... :)

Comment: Ah, okay. By the way, I'm not sure it's the best idea to name this command `\zdotfill`, because the `dotfill` module of the [zref](https://ctan.org/pkg/zref) package already has a `\zdotfill`, which works differently.

Comment: I've made slight changes to the `\zdotfill` / `\mindotfill` definition: 1) The `\nolinebreak` doesn't need to be in the group where `\hfill` is redefined; 2) `\relax` is better than the space token to prevent taking stuff such as `minus 1cm` from what follows in `\dotfill`'s definition (this doesn't happen with the current def, but is better in principle).

Comment: Actually, adding the `\relax` here is debatable. Adding it makes the expansion of the new `\hfill` contain more than just a 〈skip〉, even if it doesn't change the output; not adding it makes us rely on how it is used, i.e., on the fact that in `\dotfill`'s definition, the `\hfill` is not followed by a `plus` or a `minus` keyword. This is probably a reasonably safe assumption, and I assume that is the reason why David Carlisle didn't add the `\relax`.