# Paragraph formatting with neg indentation of first line

Tags: align, indentation, paragraphs

The follwoing result is easily accieved in Word:

[image: example]

> How is this possible in Latex?

Description:

1. First line without indentation and fixed tabulator at, say, 2 cm
2. Starting from the second line, indentation of 2 cm

That is, if the first column is short enough , then there is a tabulator (or a jump to the second column) otherwise the line extends in the second column and is separated by a comma+space.

Can a glossary handle such a thing? At the end this should be combined with [my post here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/491423).

Comment: That can be easily done with a description list and the enumitem package.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I didn't look recently in the documentation of `enumitem`, but would it really handle the conditional appending of the comma?

Comment: @frougon you can always measure the label and do something depending on the length.

Comment: @UlrikeFicher Hmm, right. But that's not competely out-of-the-box available behavior, then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve the result with `enumitem`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newlength{\commalabelwd}
\newcommand{\commalabel}[2]{%
  \settowidth\commalabelwd{\normalfont\itshape#2,\hspace{\labelsep}}%
  \normalfont\itshape#2\ifdim#1<\commalabelwd,\fi\hfill
}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}[
  labelwidth=\dimexpr2cm-\labelsep,
  leftmargin=2cm,
  before={\renewcommand\makelabel[1]{\commalabel{2cm}{##1}}}
]
\item[Short] \lipsum[1][1-2]

\item[Longer] \lipsum[1][1-2]

\item[Longerr] \lipsum[1][1-2]

\item[Longerrr] \lipsum[1][1-2]

\item[Longerrrr] \lipsum[1][1-2]

\item[Longerrrrr] \lipsum[1][1-2]

\item[Longerrrrrr] \lipsum[1][1-2]

\item[Longerrrrrrr] \lipsum[1][1-2]

\item[Longerrrrrrrrrrrrr] \lipsum[1][1-2]
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't do the conditional comma addition mentioned in the question...

Comment: @frougon Right, I oversaw it. Fixed.

Comment: very interesting solution and with less verbosity as the other; the use of `\mathscr` in the item label has the consequence that the content of the item is treated as maths environment; example `\item[$\mathscr{P}[a,b]$ ] set of all partitions`, then "set of all..." is in maths mode

Comment: @PeptideChain You need to protect the brackets in the optional argument: `\item[{$\mathscr{P}[a,b]$}]`, otherwise the *first* `]` would be taken as the delimiter; this is a common problem with optional arguments.

Comment: thank you, I understand now! with `{....}` it works. I already had this problem months ago...and I changed the label...

Answer (score 2):

I had to solve exactly the same problem not long ago. The approach is similar to that of frougon:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[papersize={5.5in,8.5in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%% Change the optional argument to suit -- 1in in this case
\newcommand{\hangit}[2][1in]{%
    \hangindent#1
    \setbox0=\hbox{\itshape#2\space}
    \noindent
    \ifdim\wd0>\myhang
        \textit{#2,}\space
    \else
        \hbox to #1{\box0\hfill}%
    \fi
    \ignorespaces
}

%% #1 default indent; #2 text in indent; #3 main text; #4 text after dot leaders
\newcommand{\hangitpar}[4][1in]{%
    \hangindent#1
    \setbox0=\hbox{\itshape#2\space}
    \noindent
    \ifdim\wd0>\myhang
        \textit{#2,}\space
    \else
        \hbox to #1{\box0\hfill}%
    \fi
    #3\mindotfill#4%
}

\newcommand{\mindotfill}{%
  \nolinebreak
  {\def\hfill{\hskip 1cm plus 1fill\relax}%
   \dotfill
  }%
}

%% Same, but uses an argument delimited with a +
%% Requires \newlength{\myhang} 
%% Could also be given explicitely in the \def
\newlength{\myhang}
\setlength{\myhang}{1in}
\def\hhangit#1+{%
    \hangindent\myhang
    \setbox0=\hbox{\itshape#1\space}
    \noindent
    \ifdim\wd0>\myhang
        \textit{#1,}\space
    \else
        \hbox to \myhang{\box0\hfill}%
    \fi
    \ignorespaces
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[5][1-4]

\hangitpar{A longer test of sorts}{\lipsum[7][4-7]}{123}

\hangit{First one}\lipsum[3][4-7]

%% Use of optional argument:
\hangit[0.75in]{Second is a bit longer}\lipsum[8][4-7]

%% Use of + delimited argument:
\hhangit And this is the next longer+ \lipsum[9][4-7]\mindotfill 123

\lipsum[6][1-4]

\end{document}
```

[image: Text in hanging indent plus dot leaders]

## Update

The OP's request for dot leaders finally sank in. I have altered the code and the example accordingly. The code for `\mindotfill` is taken from frougon's answer in [Adjusting dotfill for custom table of notations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/491423/adjusting-dotfill-for-custom-table-of-notations)

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newlength{\myColWidth}
\setlength{\myColWidth}{4em}
\newlength{\myColSep}
\setlength{\myColSep}{1em}

% A comma is appended if, and only if \widthof{#1} >= \myColWidth-\myColSep.
% The second column always starts at \myColWidth from the left margin. In
% other words, \myColSep is internal to the first column.
\newenvironment{conceptEntry}[1]{%
  \smallskip\par\noindent
  \hangindent=\myColWidth\hangafter=1\relax
  \setbox0=\hbox{#1}%
  \ifdim\wd0<\dimexpr \myColWidth-\myColSep \relax
    \hbox to \myColWidth{\box0\hfil}%
  \else
    \setbox0=\hbox{\box0, }%
    \ifdim\wd0<\myColWidth
      \hbox to \myColWidth{\box0\hfil}%
    \else
      \box0\relax
    \fi
  \fi
  \ignorespaces
}{%
  \par
  \ignorespacesafterend
}

\newcommand*{\showCommaThreshold}{%
  \par\noindent
  \begingroup
    \color{blue}%
    \rule{\dimexpr \myColWidth-\myColSep\relax}{1pt}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}
The entry text (\emph{Lorem ipsum} here) starts precisely at
\verb|\myColWidth| from the left margin. In blue, we show the tunable
threshold for the entry key width, after which a comma is appended (its value
is \verb|\myColWidth-\myColSep|):
\showCommaThreshold

\begin{conceptEntry}{Short}
  \lipsum[1][1-4]
\end{conceptEntry}

\showCommaThreshold
\begin{conceptEntry}{Longe.}
  \lipsum[1][1-4]
\end{conceptEntry}

\showCommaThreshold
\begin{conceptEntry}{Longer}
  \lipsum[1][1-4]
\end{conceptEntry}

\begin{conceptEntry}{Even longer}
  \lipsum[1][1-4]
\end{conceptEntry}
\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot]

For the dotted line you seem to want to add afterwards, I would try to get inspiration from `\@dottedtocline` (a LaTeX macro used to typeset “dotted lines” table of contents entries—see [source2e.pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/base/source2e.pdf)). The essential idea is to reserve space to the right of the paragraph using `\rightskip`, except that this space can be occupied by the last line of the paragraph (which ends with dots and the page or whatever number). This is what the following setup:

```
\rightskip \@tocrmarg \parfillskip -\rightskip
```

ensures in the definition of `\@dottedtocline`, where `\@tocrmarg` is the

> right margin indentation for all but last line of multiple-line entries

(quote from [source2e.pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/base/source2e.pdf)).

Comment: the solution works perfectly, nice idea to have two parameters to control the behavior. I'm looking into the problem of the filling with dots, because this is the way I have to follow, and I have to adapt your answer to the other Q. I'm looking the code in the link. If I can't solve it , I'll open a new Q. Thank you

Comment: Starting from [egreg's solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/491502/73317) (which I confess leads to a nicer input syntax), you can obtain [this](https://imgur.com/d8tXKit.png). The horizontal rule at the top has length `\textwidth`, and I used this morning's `\mindotfill`. This is 11 relatively short lines away from egreg's solution. :-) Input syntax for a term is like `\item[Short] \lipsum[1][1-2]\glosspagenum{3}`.

Comment: 1) The 11 lines don't count `\mindotfill`'s definition (6 lines). 2) For those who pass by, “this morning's `\mindotfill`” referred to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/491423/adjusting-dotfill-for-custom-table-of-notations/491433#491433).

Comment: where is the `\glosspagenum` defined? how do you have generated the picture? I think, that I have missed a step

Comment: Thank you, I added a new question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/491535/  if you like you can post the MWC (? minimal working code)

Comment: It's all [there](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/491536/73317) now. :-)